# How can I group my array into groups of 3 elements, sort them by the last element and display the elements?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach

I'm trying to display my array in groups of 3 elements, sorted by the last element of each group.

My array:

```
$info = array('goal','raul','80','foul','moneer','20','offside','ronaldo','60');
```

My expected output is:

```
1-foul moneer 20
2-offside ronaldo 60
3-goal raul 80
```

Sorted by the last value of the element groups.

I'm using foreach to display it:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($info as $key => $val) {
    $i++;
    echo $info[$key] . '<br>';
    if ($i % 3 == 0){
        echo "<br />";
}
```

Is this possible ? And if yes, how can I change my code to get my expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you:

First we [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) your array into chunks of 3 elements, so your array will have this structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => goal
            [1] => raul
            [2] => 80
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => foul
            [1] => moneer
            [2] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => offside
            [1] => ronaldo
            [2] => 60
        )

)
```

After this we sort it by the last value (here key 2), with [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) by simply comparing the values. Then at the end you can just loop through your array and display the data.

```
<?php

    $info = array('goal','raul','80','foul','moneer','20','offside','ronaldo','60');
    $arr = array_chunk($info, 3);
    usort($arr, function($a, $b){
        return $a[2] <=> $b[2];
    });
    
    foreach($arr as $k => $v)
        echo ($k+1) . "-" . implode(" ", $v) . "<br>";

?>
```

output:

```
1-foul moneer 20
2-offside ronaldo 60
3-goal raul 80
```