# Generate new table after 10 iteration of tr tags

Tags: php

I have a table with looping tr tags I am looking to break after every second tr tag.
like

My table looks like this after the for loop.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>12</td>
```

after modulo logic, I want to show'em like this

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is my PHP script so far.
I have tried all sort of arrangement b
ut unable to achieve those layout

```
<?php $num = 1; ?>
<table class="Table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php 
for ( $x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++ ) { 
    if($num%2 == 0) { 
?>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
<?php   
    } 
?>

<?php 
    if($num %2 == 1) { 
?>
<table class="Table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php   
    } 
    $num++;
} 
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I know I am doing a silly mistake but can't figure it out.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: You better have to create two distinct table, and split your loop, a first one for(i = 1 to 6), a second one for(i = 7 to 12). Also, fixing your indentation would help you not to be lost in your tables and loops.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30763564/2943403, https://stackoverflow.com/q/54212389/2943403

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62098442/2943403

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that returns you a table. For every dataset of size 6, call the function and get your table. You can use [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to chunk the datasets into smaller chunks and use [`heredoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax for better readability.

**getTable() function:**

```
<?php

function getTable($data){
    $table = <<<EOD
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
EOD;
    $rows = "";
    foreach(array_chunk($data,3) as $values){
        $rows .= "<tr>";
        foreach($values as $value){
            $rows .= "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
        }
        $rows .= "/<tr>";
    }
    
    $table .= $rows;
    $table .= <<<EOD
    </tbody>
    </table>
EOD;
    return $table;
}
```

**Driver code:**

```
<?php

$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];

foreach(array_chunk($arr,6) as $set_for_table){
    echo getTable($set_for_table);
}
```

Comment: It works, but what if `$arr = [1,2,3,4,5];` ? I guess that some warnings will be thrown.

Comment: @Syscall in which line did you receive warnings?

Comment: Depending of the given array. `$values[1]` or `$values[2]` could be undefined, if `$arr`'s size is not a multiple of 3. [Here is an example](https://3v4l.org/JCpUN).

Comment: @Syscall Fixed it.

Comment: Please close duplicate questions instead of answering them.

Comment: I was so spoiled for choice, I managed to find a duplicate page that @nice_dev and I closed together in the past.

Comment: @mickmackusa Oops, sorry about that, I got too carried away for using heredoc. Will close from next time if I find one :)

Comment: @RoshanKumar apparently, this is a working solution if you noticed!!!